# How to show that two reccurence relations are equal?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I encountered the following problem:

[image]

I've never seen this on tutorials or similar. How could i go about proving this? I tried using induction but its looking pretty grim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Induction works, with just one tricky bit. I’ll use $G$ to denote the function with the second-order recurrence and show by induction that it’s equal to the original $F$.

Let $G(0)=2$, $G(1)=4$, and $G(n)=4G(n-1)-3G(n-2)$ for $n\ge 2$. Clearly $G(0)=F(0)$ and $G(1)=F(1)$. Suppose that $n\ge 2$, and $G(k)=F(k)$ for $0\le k<n$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
G(n)&=4G(n-1)-3G(n-2)\\
&=4F(n-1)-3F(n-2)\\
&\overset{(*)}=4F(n-1)-\big(F(n-1)+2\big)\\
&=3F(n-1)-2\\
&=F(n)\,,
\end{align*}$$

and the result follows by induction. The one tricky step is starred. For that step I used the recurrence for $F$ with the index shifted down one: $F(n-1)=3F(n-2)-2$. The previous step is of course just the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you! Very understandable :)

Comment: @Hristmar: You’re welcome!